# how to access the parameters as array powershell

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why I can't access the value of the param .

```
cls


function __main{
    param(
          [string]$coche,  
          [string]$casa
        )

    foreach($i in $param){

        write-host "$i"
        
    }
}

__main coche casa
```

output:

```
PS C:\>
```

expected output:

```
coche
casa
```

I know they can be called one by one with $car or $house but that's not the case because then I should create an array and I don't want that:

```
cls


function __main{
    param(
          [string]$coche,  
          [string]$casa
        )

$arr = @($coche,$casa)

    foreach($i in $arr){

        write-host "$i"
      
        
    }
}

__main coche casa
```

Comment: `$args` is an array of values for undeclared parameters that are passed to a function and you only passed declared parameters. I suggest you have a read of `Get-Help about_functions` and try the examples.

Comment: Ditto to what 'jfrmilner' said. What are you trying to do? [You are also not using the proper naming construct for PS functions, etc.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+function+naming+best+practices%27&t=h_&ia=web) Yet, PS allows one to do whatever one chooses. Well, in many places.  ;-}. I get it, coming from other languages, we have our habits we bring with us.

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment.

You can check what your code doing (and more, like parameter binding) using this approach as well.

[See this: Trace-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.2)

```
 function __main{
    param(
          [string]$coche,  
          [string]$casa
        )

    foreach($i in $param){

        write-host "$i"
        
    }
}

__main coche casa

Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {__main coche casa} -PSHost
# Results
<#
The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:7 char:19
+     foreach($i in $param){
+                   ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (param:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
 
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND arg [coche] to parameter [coche]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         result returned from DATA GENERATION: coche
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [coche] to param [coche] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND arg [casa] to parameter [casa]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         result returned from DATA GENERATION: casa
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [casa] to param [casa] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Out-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [out-lineoutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Format-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [format-default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformat
ionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformat
ionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformat
ionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformat
ionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
The variable '$param' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:7 char:19
+     foreach($i in $param){
+                   ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (param:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
 
#>

 function __main{
    param(
          [string]$coche,  
          [string]$casa
        )

$arr = @($coche,$casa)

    foreach($i in $arr){

        write-host "$i"
      
        
    }
}

__main coche casa

Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {__main coche casa} -PSHost

# Results
<#
coche
casa
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND arg [coche] to parameter [coche]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         result returned from DATA GENERATION: coche
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [coche] to param [coche] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND arg [casa] to parameter [casa]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         result returned from DATA GENERATION: casa
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [casa] to param [casa] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND REMAININGARGUMENTS cmd line args to param: [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to parameter [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to param [Object] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
coche
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND REMAININGARGUMENTS cmd line args to param: [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to parameter [Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to param [Object] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Write-Host]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
casa
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
#>
```

If you are just trying to see what params are in a command, then try this:

```
(Get-Command -Name __main).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name __main).Parameters.Keys
```

Params are used to provide values to them for processing of course and be used in AutoComplete efforts. Writing a function to try and spit out its params is not really a thing. Hence the above.